# How to keep the delimiters by using df.str.split() with multipe delimiters

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

The dataframe I have been working in has a column that indicate datetime with time zone, like that : 2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00.

```
                    Horodate
0  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00
1  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00
2  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00
3  2019-01-23T04:30:00-01:00
```

I woud like to get timezone information and put it into another column called "TimeZone". I could do that by applying this function :

```
df["TimeZone"] = "+"  + df["Horodate"].str.split('[+]').str[1]
```

That works fine:

```
                    Horodate TimeZone
0  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
1  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
2  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
3  2019-01-23T04:30:00-01:00      NaN
```

but it is valable only for timezone that starts with "+". I would like to find a way to extract the whole information about time zone,including signal  "+" or "-" and get a dataframe that looks like that :

```
                    Horodate TimeZone
0  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
1  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
2  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
3  2019-01-23T04:30:00-01:00   -01:00
```

I think I have to pass to split multiple delimeters but the problem is, how to include the delimater at the same time I need to split the string ? 
I can obtain a good result just slicing the string like that :

```
df_test["TimeZone"] =  df_test["Horodate"].str[19:]
```

but it's not a generical way to do that. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just string slicing?

```
In [285]: df["TimeZone"] = df["Horodate"].str[-6:] 

In [286]: df
Out[286]: 
                    Horodate TimeZone
0  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
1  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
2  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
3  2019-01-23T04:30:00-01:00   -01:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a `regex` pattern:

```
df['TimeZone'] =  df['Horodate'].str.extract(r'([+-]\d{2}:\d{2})')
```

[out]

```
                    Horodate TimeZone
0  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
1  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
2  2019-01-23T04:30:00+01:00   +01:00
3  2019-01-23T04:30:00-01:00   -01:00
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.sub` allow regexes, so you could do:

```
df['Timezone'] = df.Horodate.str.replace('(.*)([+-])(.*)', r'\2\3')
```